# Iterator.class vs Iterator<String>.class

Tags: java, reflection

I wanted to obtain class object of Iterator and discovered that

```
 Iterator<String>.class
```

is not valid. This highlighted a question if its possible at all to use

```
 ".class"
```

syntax for

```
Object<T>
```

kind of objects in Java.

If yes, then how it can be done?
If not, what are the alternatives ?

I am doing Mocking for Iterator using Mockito's

```
Mockito.mock(Class<T>)
```

syntax.

Comment: That is very complicated way of asking the same question. People with this problem may find it difficult to find that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this because generics in Java are implemented using erasure i.e. you don't get specialized version of your classes for each type parameter used at runtime. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652692/using-mockito-to-mock-classes-with-generic-parameters) in case it didn't turn up in your search.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The way that generics are implemented in Java, they only exist at compile time, for the purpose of type checking.