# How to mock method with generic argument type

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have this method

```
public <T, R> R deepCopy(T source, R destination) {
   beanMapper.map(source, destination);
   return destination;
}
```

and want to mock with different method params like

```
mock.deepCopy(classA(), classB()).thenReturn(classB());
mock.deepCopy(classB(), classC()).thenReturn(classC());
```

but getting class cast exception.

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652692/using-mockito-to-mock-classes-with-generic-parameters

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I'm looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
doAnswer(invocation -> {
       Object arg1 = invocation.getArguments()[0];
       Object arg2 = invocation.getArguments()[1];

       if(arg1 instanceof Integer && arg2 instanceof String)
           return "something";
        if(arg1 instanceof String && arg2 instanceof Boolean)
            return false;

        return false;
}).when(yourmock).deepCopy(any(), any());
```

Now if you pass call the method with arguments (1, "abcd"), the mock willreturn "something". And if you pass ("abcd", true) then it returns false