# ClassCastException on attempt to mock Querydsl SQLQueryFactory

Tags: mockito, classcastexception, querydsl

Trying to mock SQLQueryFactory of Querydsl for DAO unit testing. Using Mockito's deep stub for the very first time.
Below is the minimal code which fails

```
@Test
void tryMockQueryDsl() {
    SQLQueryFactory sql = Mockito.mock(SQLQueryFactory.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    Mockito.when(sql.select(ArgumentMatchers.<Expression<?>>any())
            .from(ArgumentMatchers.<Expression<?>>any())
            .fetchFirst()
    ).thenReturn(null);
}
```

with the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.querydsl.sql.ProjectableSQLQuery$MockitoMock$1584151766 cannot be cast to class com.querydsl.sql.SQLQuery (com.querydsl.sql.ProjectableSQLQuery$MockitoMock$1584151766 and com.querydsl.sql.SQLQuery are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Mocks can not be cast. Instead of `RETURN_DEEP_STUBS` mock each method on its own and return a mocked instance of the expected class.

If you do not want to suppress the warnings you will get for not defining the generic types, you can use the `@Mock` annotation instead to create the mocks, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687353/11514534).

This example doesn't make much sense for a testcase (as it tests nothing), but its a showcase on how to avoid the exception.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {

    @Test
    public void tryMockQueryDsl() {

        ProjectableSQLQuery projectableQuery = Mockito.mock(ProjectableSQLQuery.class);

        // not really needed as this is the default behaviour
        Mockito.when(projectableQuery.fetchFirst()).thenReturn(null);

        SQLQuery query = Mockito.mock(SQLQuery.class);
        Mockito.when(query.from(ArgumentMatchers.<Expression<?>>any())).thenReturn(projectableQuery);

        SQLQueryFactory sql = Mockito.mock(SQLQueryFactory.class);      
        Mockito.when(sql.select(ArgumentMatchers.<Expression<?>>any())).thenReturn(query);

        Expression expr = Mockito.mock(Expression.class);
        sql.select(expr).from(expr).fetchFirst();
    }
}
```