# How to mock a Jetpack Datastore in a Espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-preferences, datastore

I switched from SharedPreferences to Jetpack DataStore.

I am unable to mock the data from the datastore call in the Instrumentation test

In declaration

```
 val dataStore = context.createDataStore(name = "App Name")
```

In the declaration get a string from preferences

```
   suspend fun getString(
        key: Preferences.Key<String>,
        defaultVal: String,
        context: Context
    ): String {
        return dataStore?.data?.catch {
            if (it is IOException) {
                it.printStackTrace()
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw it
            }
        }?.map {
            it[key] ?: defaultVal
        }?.first() ?: ""
    }
```

In the usage

```
 SharedPreferenceHelper.getString(
                Preferences.Key<T>,
                "",
                requireContext()
            )
```

Manipulate datastore preferences string key to get mocked value in instrumentation test as the desired value.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`createDataStore` returns `DataStore<Preference>`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652692/using-mockito-to-mock-classes-with-generic-parameters) will help you to create mock of Class with generic type

Or you can use [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin) to create mock like this in kotlin

```
 val mockDataStore = mock<DataStore<Preference>>()
```